# MapBox GL in Salesforce LWC

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to use MapBox GL inside a Salesorce LWC component, I downloaded the mapbox-gl.js and mapbox-gl.css  as static ressource in SF, and used loadscript and loadstyle, the load pass. but since i start reference mapboxgl to work with it tell me : mapboxgl is undefined.
Of course I turned on LWS (Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura components), any advice, experience with please ?